# Appending values from one array, if value in another array is greater than a certain value, else append that value

Tags: python, arrays, append, comparison

Say for example I have two arrays of equal length.

```
x = np.array([-34, 1, -12, 4, 5, -5])

y = np.array([2, -1, 4, 6, 7, 4])
```

I want to create a new array or list of equal length where if the value of x is less than a certain number (g) then it appends (g) otherwise it will append y.

So in the above two arrays lets say if x is less than -5 it will append -5, otherwise it will append the value of y. It would turn out to the following:

```
new_array = ([-5, -1, -5, 6, 7, 4])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply with `np.where`, e.g.:

```
In []:
np.where(x < -5, -5, y)

Out[]:
array([-5, -1, -5,  6,  7,  4])
```

Comment: Very clean - note that this does indeed create a new `numpy` array, which may be what is needed, the other answers result in lists (not `numpy` arrays) and would need something like `np.array(result)` to convert them.

Comment: I converted two pandas df columns into arrays x and y. When I tried this it says:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly:

- you want to create a new array based on `x` and `y`, that has the same length as `x` and `y`, but for each element of `x`, if it is less than some number `g`, it is `g`, otherwise it is the matching value from `y` at the same index.

A solution:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-34, 1, -12, 4, 5, -5])
y = np.array([2, -1, 4, 6, 7, 4])
g = -5

result = [g if ax < g else ay for ax, ay in zip(x, y)]
```

Note that:

- `zip()` takes two iterables and combines them into a single iterable, pairing up the values from each input. So, it takes `x` and `y` and turns them into [ (-34, 2), (1, -1), etc.]
- the list comprehension loops over those pairs and performs the operation you specified: if `ax` from `x` is less than `g`, the result includes `g`, otherwise it gets the matched `ay` from `y`

As a followup, OP asked how to find the `g` so that the sum of the `result` would be maximised (for negative values of `g`). A simple brute force approach:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-34, 1, -12, 4, 5, -5])
y = np.array([2, -1, 4, 6, 7, 4])

prev_s = None
best_g = None
best_result = None

for g in range(min(x), 0):
    values = [g if ax < g else ay for ax, ay in zip(x, y)]
    s = sum(values)
    if best_result is None or s > prev_s:
        prev_s = s
        best_g = g
        best_result = values

print(best_g, best_result)
```

Note that for the given example data, the answer to that is an uninteresting `6, [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`. (Uninteresting because you can keep increasing `g` endlessly and the result will always be greater - your question is oddly stated)

Comment: Think you meant for ax, ay in zip(x, y) rather than for ax, ay from zip(x, y)

Comment: You're right - I fixed the typo in code, but not in the answer, thanks. It's correct now

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, thank you. This works as needed!

Comment: New question if you don't mind answering. How would I find a value of g that maximizes the result. Find g that maximizes sum(result)?

Comment: Doing that in a smart way (maximizing the result) would require some more thought, but a simple brute force approach would be to start g at the minimum value in `x` and loop to just above the maximum value in `x` (i.e. `for g in range(min(x), max(x)+2):`) and whenever the sum is greater than previously, keep that value of `g` and the `result`.

Comment: Lets say we have: x = [-23, -44, -55, -5] and y = [40, 25, -30, 20] if g is -6 then result = [-6, -6, -6, 20] and the sum = 2 however if g = -40 then result = [40, -40, -40, 20] and sum = -20

Comment: All x array values are negative in real data. G has to be a negative value.

Comment: In your new code I think I should just set the g range(min, max) to my x(min, max) in this case if they are all negative.

Comment: x = [-3, -9, -3, -4, -11, -12, -14]
y = [-2, 10, 12, -3, 4,-1222, 67]
for g in range(min(x), 0):
   ......... this did it for a result of g = [-11] to maximize result

Comment: Updated - can you accept the answer to close the question, if you feel this has answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to iterate over each item in the `x` array based on its index. In case the element in `x` isn't less than -5, you can easily reference the same element in `y` using the same index used for `x`.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-34, 1, -12, 4, 5, -5])
y = np.array([2, -1, 4, 6, 7, 4])
newList = []
number = -5
for i in range(len(x)):
  if x[i] < number:
    newList.append(number)
  else:
    newList.append(y[i])
```

Comment: Although it certainly works, looping over a pair of lists using an integer index like this isn't very Pythonic

Comment: @Grismar what is Pythonic then?

Comment: This problem is a typical example where using a list comprehension is a good solution. It prevents introducing extra variables and code that is part of the language - see the answer I provided for an example. Also note that using `zip()` is very efficient, it doesn't create an entirely new copy of the data if it doesn't have to (which is a reason why people sometimes do what you did). Note that my answer does in 1 line what yours does in 7, without sacrificing clarity, I think.

Comment: @Grismar I didn't even know the `zip()` function existed or that you could use syntax like that in Python! Even though it wasn't my question, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for your answer as well - it helps new coders to see different solutions side by side and yours is a good standard way of implementing this that would work in many languages. Python is just a really nice language for this type of problem.

Comment: This is something very similar to what I was trying Fadi, and this one works! Appreciate the quick responses from everyone, love this site now!